# Adjusting excel column widths according to the selection of certain rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing a macro where I want to change column-width according to certain row selections. How can I do this using excel vba?

So for example I want to do something like the following:

```
  With Sheet22.Range(var22b)
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 40
  End With


  With Sheet22.Range(var22c)
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 90
  End With
```

Comment: You have a mess on the `With` if you are changin columns, there is no need for a range, so you need to use `With Sheet22` (If sheet22 is a  variable and is already set). Then use `.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 90`

Comment: Thanks @Damian but Sheet22 is te Sheet number and the var22b contains the range.. I want to print a set or rows with a certain column with and the width of the same column again when I choose another range within the same sheet..

Comment: The columnwidth is set for the whole column not for a range. Do you want to change the column width IF something or set the column width AND do something?

Comment: @MEnum Then `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet22")` if the code is within the workbook you are trying to change the width.